# problems with PyPlot on Jupyter-lab

Tags: matplotlib, julia, jupyter

I am starting getting this message when using PyPlot in Jupyter lab, tried Pkg.resolve() but it didn't help, does anyone knows how to fix this?

many thanks!!

```
using PyPlot
┌ Info: Precompiling PyPlot [d330b81b-6aea-500a-939a-2ce795aea3ee]
└ @ Base loading.jl:1278
┌ Warning: Package FixedPointNumbers does not have Statistics in its dependencies:
│ - If you have FixedPointNumbers checked out for development and have
│   added Statistics as a dependency but haven't updated your primary
│   environment's manifest file, try `Pkg.resolve()`.
│ - Otherwise you may need to report an issue with FixedPointNumbers
└ Loading Statistics into FixedPointNumbers from project dependency, future warnings for FixedPointNumbers are suppressed.
```

Comment: did you try this: ```pip install matplotlib```

Comment: yes, at the end I had to reinstall matplotlib, now all is fine
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, running `Pkg.resolve()` from the jupyter workbook fixed it, I had been trying from the REPL, as I thought it was equivalent, and it wasn't forking bu now is fine.